# RHEL4 - 2.6.9-55 TO UPDATE 8

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rhel4

I am having clearcase 7.0.1 application running on RHEL 4.0 (Paid & Unregistered)with the kernel version 2.6.9-55. When we ask the support redhat they said its not possiable because its not registered.

As the patch of the clearcase need to be updated we need to update present kernel to Update8 kernel.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Help you to steal RHEL?

Answer (score 2):

You can either register your server with Red Hat and update once you're entitled.

or

If you're not registered, you can [convert the system to CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide) and apply your updates.